# How to center the navigation on a drop down menu?

Tags: css, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to center the navigation on my drop down menu and I can't seem to figure out how to.

Here is a screen shot of how its left aligned on a fixed 900px width.

[image]

Here is my CSS:

```
#cssmenu {
  border: none;
  border: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight:600;
  color: #FFF;
  line-height: 30px;
  width: 900px;
}

#cssmenu ul {
  background: #000000;
  height: 30px;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#cssmenu li {
  float: left;
  padding: 0px;
}

#cssmenu li a {
  background: #000000;
  display: block;
  font-weight: 600;
  line-height: 30px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px 33px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#cssmenu > ul > li > a {
  color: #ffffff;
}

#cssmenu ul ul a {
  color: #ffffff;
}

#cssmenu li > a:hover,
#cssmenu ul li:hover > a {
  background: #4ba5a1;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#cssmenu li ul {
  background: #333333;
  display: none;
  height: auto;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  border: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 155px;
  z-index: 225;
  /*top:1em;/*left:0;*/
}

#cssmenu li:hover ul {
  display: block;
}

#cssmenu li li {
  background-color: #2b2b2b;
  display: block;
  float: none;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  width: 225px;
}

#cssmenu li:hover li a {
  background: none;
}

#cssmenu li ul a {
  display: block;
  height: 30px;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-style: normal;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px 10px 0px 15px;
  text-align: left;
}

#cssmenu li ul a:hover,
#cssmenu li ul li:hover > a {
  background: #4ba5a1;  
  border: 0px;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#cssmenu p {
  clear: left;
}
```

Comment: Please use JSFiddle to arrange your example code

Comment: Show us some HTML Code to set up a jsfiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shoudl try to center the list `#cssmenu ul{ margin:0 auto;}`

Comment: Thank you so much! I had to remove the padding and add the auto to the margin.